# How to apply KKT conditions (to minimization) to solve maximization problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

Consider the following problem
$$ \max x_1^2+4x_1x_2+x_2^2 \\ s.t. x_1^2+x_2^2=1 $$

a. Using conditions KKT, find the candidates to be solution.

b. Using second order conditions, stablish  the status of the candidates founded in a.

c. Does the problem has a unique solution?

My question

The KKT conditions that I have in my notes are only for minimization problems $\min f$.

The structure of the Theorem is *Consider minimization problem f s.t. Ax< b. If x is a KKT point, then x is a minimum of f*.

How can I use the Theorem I have to solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can restate your problem equivalently as the minimization of $-(x_1^2+4x_1x_2+x_2^2)$ subject to the same constraint. Any solution to this problem will be a solution to your problem and viceversa.